# Storing and retrieving objects from SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, intellij-idea

I'm trying to store an object (serialized) in SQLite, then retrieve and deserialize the object back into the original object...

So far I have managed to write the code to store the object (I think)

```
public void addLookup( LookupData lookupData ){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();


    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_PERSON, lookupData.getPersonName());
    values.put(KEY_PERSONOBJECT, Serializer.serializeObject(lookupData));
    values.put(KEY_DATETIME, lookupData.getDatetime());

    db.insert(TABLE_LOOKUPS, null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

But I'm struggling with getting the data out again:

```
public PersonData getLookup( Integer id ){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_LOOKUPS, new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_PERSON, KEY_PERSONOBJECT, KEY_DATETIME }, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null );
    if( cursor != null )
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    LookupData lookupData = Serializer.deserializeObject(cursor.getBlob(2));
}
```

Because deserializeObject expects byte[] IntelliJ is complaining that cursor.getString(2), or cursor.getBlob(2) won't work.

To be honest I'm out of my depth with this. How do you guys serialize, store, retrieve and deserialize back into objects again?

Comment: `I'm trying to store an object (serialized) in SQLite` Why would you do this? If you're just going to store serialized binary data, do it in a flat file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented this is almost always inferior to using a flat file for binary data.

If you need to link a file to each row in a table the best way is to store URIs as strings.

This question could be helpful in getting URIs to save and finding the files from the URIs [Can I get Uri of image file from its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174732/can-i-get-uri-of-image-file-from-its-name/2174743)

Comment: A much better way of handling it, thank you. I don't know why I discounted this in the first instance.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Ormlite](http://ormlite.com/) framework, it provides some simple, lightweight functionality for persisting Java objects to SQL databases

Answer (score 0):

[greenDAO](http://greendao-orm.com/) is a straightforward, lightweight object-relational mapping library for Android/SQLite. It is easy to set up and is probably more along the lines of what you are trying to do, as long as your source data is structured into classes that map to database tables and has member data that maps to database fields. It handles one-to-one and one-to-many mappings as well.